# Insert a button into each parent div of an <img> tag

Tags: javascript, html

So, basically, what I need to do is to get every image from the page that I'm currently on (in this case I've got 2) and I need to insert a button to it.
The approach that I'm trying is targeting all the images, and placing a button in their parent div.
I've attempted to achieve this with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
}

.container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.container .btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.container .btn:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <img src="123.png">
</div>
    
<div class="container">
  <img src="223.png">
</div>


    
<script type="text/javascript">
var imgscount = document.querySelectorAll("img")
var imgs_array = [...imgscount]; 
    
    
for(var i = 0; i< document.images.length; i++)
    {
        var imgs = document.querySelector("img");
        for (var j = 0; j < imgs_array.length-1; j++)
        {
            imgs.parentElement.innerHTML = imgs.parentElement.innerHTML +'<button class="btn">Button</button>';
        };

    };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Although, `imgs.parentElement.innerHTML = imgs.parentElement.innerHTML +'<button class="btn">Button</button>';` creates two buttons in the same `<div>`, instead of 1 button per each `<div>`.

This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bG5X.png) should explain better what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: You only need one `loop`. Do in the first `loop`. `document.images[i].parentElement.innerHTML = document.images[i].parentElement.innerHTML +'<button class="btn">Button</button>';`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple loop would do the trick, also I manually draw the circle to replace the images

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll("img");

for ( var i = 0; i < images.length; i++ ) {
  images[i].parentElement.innerHTML += '<button class="btn">Button</button>';
}
```

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    /*
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    */
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
}

.container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.container .btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.container .btn:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="123.png">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="223.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove this for loop

```
        for (var j = 0; j < imgs_array.length-1; j++)
```

Comment: i had tried that before adding the loop, had the same result, it still adds the button to the first div :/